# veth interfaces performance problem

Tags: linux, networking, performance, veth

On a fast AWS machine (`m5.2xlarge`), I am creating around 600 veth interfaces, each one having a little server (with `socat`) running on a port.

I then start sending around 7kb/second of data per server. When sending to about 500 servers everything goes well, but when I send it to around 600 servers, timeouts begin to occur. The connection to the server can take more than 3 seconds to be executed, as I have tested.

It's not a lot of processing (for such a server) and it's not a lot of data.

*Is the Linux `veth` implementation slow?*

I have created a [git repo to reproduce the problem](https://github.com/pallix/veth_network_namespaces_perf). Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have hit other limitations, not veth related. From your script, you already use `macvlan` (quickest "bridge").

[Here](https://cs.nju.edu.cn/tianchen/lunwen/2017/sgws-Zhao.pdf) is a link about  performance and  issues on container networking topic and how NUMA and number of threads affect networking performance of different devices.

Maybe your test/implementation must be redesigned.